# Is $Q(5^{1/4},√11,i)/Q $ normal

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I think all roots of $x^4-5$ and $x^2-11$ and $x^2+1$ are in the field but it seems impossible to find a irreducible polynomial that contains all those roots. How can we check if it is normal?

I think it is normal but cant say why.

Answer (score 2):

It is the splitting field of $ (X^2 - 11)(X^4 - 5) $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $, and since splitting fields are normal extensions, the result follows.

Comment: but how do we know that polynomia is irreducible?

Comment: We don't need to know that, splitting fields are always normal extensions.

Comment: But u said earlier that if K is a splitting field over an irreducible polynomial then K is normal...

Comment: What I said doesn't contradict that. You are just mentioning a special case (and I don't know when I said that, by the way).

Comment: Because compositums of finite normal field extensions are normal (and finite, of course). Cf. Lang, Algebra, Algebraic Extensions

Comment: @Starfall you said it my previous thread, your second comment. But in general what do we need to check if it is normal?

Comment: If $ L/K $ is a finite extension, then it is normal iff it is the splitting field of some polynomial in $ K[X] $ over $ K $.

Comment: Ok why did you ignore x^2+1?

Comment: Because the splitting field of $ X^4 - 5 $ over $ \mathbb{Q} $ already contains $ i $.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the splitting field of $x^2-11$ and $x^4-5$, the roots of $x^4-5$ are $i5^{1/4},5^{1/4},-i5^{1/4},-5^{1/4}$